# Doubts about notifications format in Orion usin APIv2

Tags: fiware-orion

we are testing the subscription functionality using the APIv2. We are following the guidelines described in http://telefonicaid.github.io/fiware-orion/api/v2/ . We are able to create a correct subscription but the format of the notification messages that we received is not what we expected. The format of these messages is like the APIv1 version. Is this the expected behavior?

We are using the Docker image from https://hub.docker.com/r/fiware/orion/.

Version information about the build:

```
{
  "orion" : {
    "version" : "1.0.0-next",
    "uptime" : "0 d, 1 h, 28 m, 47 s",
    "git_hash" : "a729812c45d2749fffbc19add17631b2fffc8797",
    "compile_time" : "Fri Apr 8 10:05:55 UTC 2016",
    "compiled_by" : "root",
    "compiled_in" : "838a42ae8431"
  }
}
```

### Steps to reproduce:

Create an entity:

```
(curl -X POST  http://<cb_url>:<cb_port>/v2/entities?options=keyValues -s -S --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
    --header 'Accept: application/json' -d @- | python -mjson.tool) <<EOF
{
  "type":"Room",
  "id": "test",
  "humidity":40
}
EOF
```

Create a subscription:

```
(curl -X POST  http://<cb_url>:<cb_port>/v2/subscriptions -s -S --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
    --header 'Accept: application/json' -d @- | python -mjson.tool) <<EOF
{
  "description": "One subscription to rule them all",
  "subject": {
    "entities": [
      {
        "idPattern": ".*",
        "type": "Room"
      }
    ],
    "condition": {
      "attributes": [
        "humidity"
      ],
      "expression": {
        "q": "humidity>40"
      }
    }
  },
  "notification": {
    "callback": "http://192.168.99.1:5000",
    "attributes": [
      "humidity"
    ],
    "throttling": 5
  },
  "expires": "2016-05-05T14:00:00.00Z"
}
EOF
```

Update attribute.:

```
(curl -X PUT <cb_url>:<cb_port>/v2/entities/test/attrs/humidity/value -s -S --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
    --header 'Accept: application/json' -d @- | python -mjson.tool) <<EOF
{
  "value": 50
}
EOF
```

We get the notification with the following format:

```
{u'contextResponses': [
   {u'contextElement': {
      u'attributes': [{
        u'name': u'humidity',
        u'type': u'none',
        u'value': {u'value': 50}
      }],
      u'id': u'test',
      u'isPattern': u'false',
      u'type': u'Room'
   },
   u'statusCode': {
      u'code': u'200',
      u'reasonPhrase': u'OK'
   }}],
 u'originator': u'localhost',
 u'subscriptionId': u'5707b72882fc213130f4e5b9'}
```

Answer (score 0):

NGSIv2 notification formats have not been yet implemented (at Orion 1.0.0). Note that NGSIv2 is yet in beta status and sometimes the specification (where the new notification format has been defined) is a step forward the implementation.

There is [a github issue about this](https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-orion/issues/1875), to which you can subscribe in order to know when this feature gets implemented.

**EDIT:** NGSIv2 notification formats have been implemented in Orion 1.1.0.

Comment: Answer has been edited to add new information about NGSIv2 implementation status in upcoming Orion release.